# Add non-Pip packages to Pip

Tags: python, build, pip

I built `OpenCV` from source via this [script](https://qengineering.eu/install-opencv-4.5-on-jetson-nano.html).

Since it's not installed using Pip, `$ pip list` doesn't have `opencv-python`.

```
$ pip list

...
MarkupSafe (1.0)
matplotlib (2.1.1)
numpy (1.13.3)
oauth (1.0.1)
oauthlib (2.0.6)
# opencv-python not available
onboard (1.4.1)
PAM (0.4.2)
pandas (0.22.0)
...
```

The problem is, when I want to create a `virtualenv`, `OpenCV` is not included.

How can I include non-Pip packages, `OpenCV` in this case, to my Pip list?

Comment: I think theres a misunderstanding here. There are no such things as pip and non-pip packages. `pip` takes python packages and handles installing them into your environments. What it can do is look at index servers to find additional packages to download, but you can just as easily point `pip` to install locally produced packages or install packages from source checkouts (which is probably what you want to do).

Comment: @flakes Thank you for explanation! What then I should do to show `OpenCV` in `pip list`? I can import OpenCV with `--system-site-packages`, but it's not visible in `pip list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @flakes for advice!

I was able to import `OpenCV` with new `virtualenv` using below command.

```sh
$ python3 -m venv --system-site-packages ENV
```